# Python support for Atom editor

Tags: python, atom-feed

I have been using atom for a while now to code html, CSS, JS. I would now like to learn python and hope to be using Atom as my editor. Is there a way to add python support to Atom. I tried a few addons for Atom but I cannot get it to work. If I try to run a python test file atom sends an error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a comment and much research later I have found a solution. You install [ide-python](https://atom.io/packages/ide-python). And follow the instructions shown. I also installed [Script](https://atom.io/packages/script) for good measure. Now Atom compiles and runs python code.